# ReactNative Set EXPO_DEBUG issue

Tags: ios, reactjs, npm, native, expo

I face an issue when I fire **expo start** in my mac terminal 
I got this message:

> Could not access packager status at `http://localhost:19001/status`. Are you sure the packager is running and reachable?
>   Set `EXPO_DEBUG=true` in your env to view the stack trace.

My `status is: running`

My `expo --version: 2.1.3`

My `npm --version: 6.4.1`

My `node --version: v10.11.0`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I'm dying trying to get an answer here

Answer (score 1):

There is no certain way of fixing it, sometimes I can solve it by clearing NPM cache:
npm cache clean --force

Sometimes I able to solve it by reinstalling expo CLI.

The other time I was able to solve it by running Expo XDE.

If it is not working for you, you may try other commands here:
https://forums.expo.io/t/how-to-clear-the-react-native-packager/1352

Comment: I found one solution. Maybe this is not a proper solution but I found one of patch solution. I replace app.json, App.test.js, package.json, package-lock.json, and node_modules folder from one of my working project & change my project name in packages file. Then I fired npm start command and It’s working.

Comment: solution provided by @ang solved the problem. Thanks